# How to connect to a DB trough two ssh connections?

Tags: networking, ssh

I am currently working with a PostgreSQL DB which I connect to using the pgAdminIII client. I use putty to connect to a IP1 through a port P1 and from there settle a tunnel to a IP2 using a source port P2 setting a listening Port P3.

I am having some connection problems, so when I query through the client I usually ended up losing my query result, thus I want to connect directly to the DB machine and using [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) query the DB directly and being able to disconnect from the remotes machines and not losing the query result.

Any ideas on how to do this? I have made some simple tryouts like ssh to IP1 using ssh, and from there ssh to IP2 but this is not working at all.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do based on your question is to SSH to the IP1 machine on port P1. Then, instead o creating a tunnel to IP2 you would launch the screen program on IP1 and use a command line postgresql query program to connect to and query the database on IP2 at port P2.

Using the screen program, as you indicated you would like to do in your question, will do away with using pgAdmin. Screen is a command line only program.

Comment: Sure I want to work through command line in order to be able to use screen, but the machine in IP1 doesn't have postgresql, so I need to connect somehow to IP2

Comment: You will either need to install a postgresql command line client on IP1 or  SSH to IP1 and then SSH from there to IP2 and use the postgresql client on there. From your question it sounded like SSH server was probably not installed on IP2 though since you were unable to connect to it.

Comment: But I have tried to ssh again to the IP2 machine from the IP1 machine and I am unable to do it (but I am perfectly capable to open the original tunnel connection...), thus my question.